# NodeJS - Mongoose Replace Space and Lowercase Words

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, mongoose

I am trying to create a tagging system with mongoose, but the issue I am finding is that I am able to save comma separated items to an array, but if I include a space, the space is saved and is not replaced by a hyphen. I'm not sure what the best approach to use regex to fix this. The final product I am looking for is,

Inputted tags in field:
tags:`test, cow, farm yard`

And have it displayed as:
tags:`test,cow,farm yard`

with routes like:
`/tag/test`
`/tag/cow`
`/tag/farm-yard`

Here is how I am recording my Schema values (to an array):

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: { type: String, unique: true },
        featureImage: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: Array, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

BlogPostSchema.post('init', function (post) {
    var date = new Date(post.date || Date.now() );
    post.dateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

Here is how I'm posting my records in my route (using the trim method):

```
router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");
            console.log(req.body.tags);

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.featureImage = req.body.featureImage; // set the blog image
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");

            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags.trim().split(","); // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method
```

Finally here is how I'm displaying the tags as links in my view:

```
<h3 class="blog-date"><%= blogpost.dateString %></h3>
                <h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3>
                <h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3>
                <p><%- blogpost.content %></p>
                <% for(var i=0; i<blogpost.tags.length; i++) { %>
                <p>Tags:<a href="/tag/<%= blogpost.tags[i] %>"><%= blogpost.tags[i] %></a></p>
                <% } %>
```

End result is displayed as individual tags within the loop which is not correct and space, non-hyphen spaces are included:

```
                <p>Tags:<a href="/tag/test">test</a></p>

                <p>Tags:<a href="/tag/ cow"> cow</a></p>

                <p>Tags:<a href="/tag/farm yard">farm yard</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a package like [string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string) and remove all spaces before saving them:

```
var S = require('string');
S(req.body.tags).replaceAll(' ', '');
```